# How Do I use or properly return a value from my PostgreSQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.first()
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  res numeric;
BEGIN
  PERFORM data.second(5,3,4);
  IF(res > 10)THEN
    something
  ELSEIF(res < 10)THEN
    something else
  END IF
END;
$BODY$;
```

=========================================

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.second(
a numeric,
b numeric,
c numeric
OUT res numeric
)
RETURNS numeric
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  res = a + b;
END;
$BODY$;
```

How do I use res in the parent function?

Comment: Try posting something *other than raw code*, such as a description of what you tried/read, where you get stuck, error messages, etc. Also, please format your code in future.

Comment: What I want To achieve is basically; to be able to check the return value from "second" function and do a condition "first" function based on "second"'s result. I have tried Selecting*FROM data.second() as dat, but Im getting " query has no destination for result data" . Sorry for the unformatted code

Comment: A google search for the error message will be informative in this case, try starting there. Look into `PERFORM` and the `SELECT ... INTO` option, and `FOUND` variable, as discussed in the plpgsql manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't specify both OUT and function returns:

```
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.second(
a numeric,
b numeric,
c numeric,
OUT res numeric
)
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
res = a + b;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

if you want to use the return of function ,use `select into VAR`, perform will just execute function discarding its output:

```
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.first() returns text
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
res numeric;
BEGIN
SELECT data.second(5,3,4) INTO res;
IF(res > 5)THEN
  raise info 'second returned %',res;
END IF;
RETURN 'here is the return';
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

finaly:

```
t=# select * from data.first();
INFO:  second returned 8
       first
--------------------
 here is the return
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html